# What is the normalization process of my Entity Relationship Diagram (ERD)?

Tags: database, normalization, erd

[image]

i cannot normalize my erd because some entity borrow other's PK

Comment: Define "some" and "other's" for example...

Comment: Your diagram is a table diagram, not an ER diagram. You also didn't list functional and other dependencies. Fundamentally, there's no problem normalizing multiple relations with the same candidate keys, so please explain your specific problems and questions.